# App Widgets and Activity stack

Tags: java, android, widget, android-appwidget

I have one simple widget consisting in a simple button that launches the main Activity. But I have a problem, when I open the app from the launcher, press the home button and relaunch the app from the widget and the activity appears twice. How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

After adding [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag 
If you have already Activity is opened and you are again starting that Activity then it will restart your Activity.It will not start another instance of Activity